# How to hide "Times" in Kendo scheduler

Tags: grouping, kendo-scheduler

If i want to disable "times" in Kendo scheduler i can use following code snippet.

```
<style scoped>.k-scheduler-times {

  display: none;

}</style>
```

If i use this style, it loses vertical grouping like "meeting room 101","meeting room 102".
I dont need times because all events are all day events.

http://trykendoui.telerik.com/ILIb

Is there any way to keep vertical grouping with week view but not shwoing times. (11:00, 12:00)

I am trying to create something like this
http://code.daypilot.org/page/image/a26hoawhl5gtle2jspxmcstcri/hotel-reservation-asp.net-rooms.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try too use the `.MinorTickCount(0)`, at-least it works for me.

Comment: I dont think kendo has a control which groups resouces(rooms) by month BUT a big thanks to you man. It is really not what i exactly want but whatever.. at least it is a temporary solution and saves a time.

Comment: Hi, i know this is a old post, but where exactly do you put this MinorTickCount(0) ? thanks